# For delete trigger is not working (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-delete

I have a table Universities and a table Cities. There is a m:n relationship between them, so the relationship is saved in a further table called CityUniversities. Now I wanted to write a trigger which deletes all relations between the tables Cities and Universities when deleting a university from Universities. However it's not working. I always receive the following error message when trying to delete a University:

"Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_CityUniversities_Universities". The conflict occurred in database "Alumni_Dev", table "dbo.CityUniversities", column 'UniversityId'.
The statement has been terminated."

That's the trigger (for table Universities) which I have implemented and succesfully executed:

```
USE [Alumni_Dev]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[deleteUni]    Script Date: 05/02/2012 11:42:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[deleteUni]
ON  [dbo].[Universities] 
FOR DELETE
AS 
DECLARE @UniId int
SELECT @UniId = (SELECT UniversityId FROM deleted)
BEGIN
--Remove constraints
DELETE FROM dbo.CityUniversities WHERE UniversityId = @UniId;
END
```

I already compared my solution with several references, however I can't find anything that could be wrong. Could it be that there are any wrong settings in one of the affected tables?

I'd be happy to hear any suggestions.

---

I finally solved my problem with the following trigger (thx to Nikola):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[deleteUni]
ON  [dbo].[Universities] 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
DECLARE @UniId int
SELECT @UniId = UniversityId FROM deleted
BEGIN
--Remove constraints
DELETE FROM dbo.CityUniversities WHERE UniversityId = @UniId;
DELETE FROM dbo.Universities WHERE UniversityId = @UniId;
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigger cannot be used to delete orphaned records from other tables because constraints are checked before trigger gets executed. You should set up [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) instead.

You might use [INSTEAD OF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175158%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) trigger also if you want to perform some checking before deletion, but don't forget to add `delete Universities where ...` at the end of a trigger to actually delete record.

Two points about triggers:

- Add [SET NOCOUNT ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) at the beginning of trigger body to avoid posibility of sql statements inside trigger changing the value of "rows affected" which you might need in calling code,
- Don't treat deleted and inserted tables as if they contain one record only. There will be nasty surprises when you try to delete two universities. You should rather join a table you work with with deleted or inserted tables, using them as filter, or use exists:

  ```
  delete dbo.CityUniversities
    from dbo.CityUniversities
   inner join deleted
      on dbo.CityUniversities.UniversityId = deleted.UniversityId
  ```

or

```
delete dbo.CityUniversities
 where exists (select null
                 from deleted
                where deleted.UniversityId =dbo.CityUniversities.UniversityId)
```

Oh, and

```
SELECT @UniId = (SELECT UniversityId FROM deleted)
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT @UniId = UniversityId FROM deleted
```